# How to compile a python file?

Tags: python, compiling

I have started learning python and I'm also a new user to Ubuntu. I need to know the ways of compiling the `.py` files. I have tried with the command

```
python "hello.py"
```

What are the other ways of compiling python?

Comment: `python -m py_compile script.py`

Answer (score 73):

Adding to Bryan's answer, if you simply want to compile a file or a bunch of files from a terminal, the `py_compile` module can be executed as a script in the following manner:

`python -m py_compile fileA.py fileB.py fileC.py ...`

Comment: If you are compiling because you want speed, you can also add the `-O` flag, like `python -O -m py_compile …`, which will “turn on basic optimizations”. It mainly strips out `assert` statements and `if __debug__` code, so for most code it has no effect. See [`man python`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/python) and [“What does Python optimization … do?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4777113/578288) for details.

Comment: That's not compilation, that's transliteration to some other representation of the python language. You still need the python interpreter to run this. In case anyone else thinks "oh *that* was a surprisingly easy answer!" and then discovers it's not actually producing a compiled binary at all.

Answer (score 30):

Also be aware that you don't *need* to compile a `.py` file to run it. Python is an interpreted language, and you can run the scripts directly, either using:

```
python hello.py
```

Or make your script executable by adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of the script, making the file executable with `chmod +x hello.py` and then running:

```
./hello.py
```

The fact that Python internally compiles your `.py` script to bytecode `.pyc` files for performance reasons is an implementation detail, and unless you have a strong reason to do so, let python itself decide when and if to compile.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this works. Doesn't the Python interpreter needs to be able to read the script in order to run it? If you give only execute permission (`chmod +x`), how is the interpreter reading the script?

Comment: @yellow01: when you execute a script that contains a "shebang", ie, first line starts with `#!/path/to/interpreter`, the kernel actually executes whatever is declared there, passing the script path as an argument. In my example, when you run `./hello.py` what is actually executed is `/usr/bin/env python ./hello.py`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: @yellow01 you are right that the interpreter will need reading permissions once started through the process MestreLion describes. However, `chmod +x` grants execute, and does not touch existing permissions so presumably it's readable in addition to now being executable.

Answer (score 17):

You may also try `compileall`:

```
python -m compileall ./
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html

Answer (score 15):

Check out this link [Compile in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm)

In the middle of the page, it talks about the py_compile module that can be imported.
The syntax is as follows:

```
import py_compile

py_compile.compile("file.py")
```

This method of compiling will not execute the module either like running python file.py.

There is also a method that compiles an entire directory tree but I'll let you check out the link to see how that is executed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

You can compile Python scripts to a binary code using various methods, but I have found out that using Nuitka is more efficient.

Nuitka is a Python-to-C++ compiler that supports almost all versions of python.

The command syntax is as easy as

```
nuitka hello.py
```

Goto http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html for more information.

Comment: More efficient how? Why would anyone want to use it?

Comment: nuitka is indeed very useful - for example, it allows you to ship Python programs to computers where Python is not installed. But as nuitka compiles Python programs to C++ machine code, you can circumvent that.